# java.exe high cpu usage

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, cpu

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 to develop a Java GUI which has a login form and a few other JInternalFrames inside a JFrame. Netbeans doesn't use high CPU but whenever I run the project and the windows open up, the cpu rises up to 90-93%. Can someone please tell me the cause of this?

Comment: I checked task manager and it shows Java Platform SE Binary as the culprit.

Comment: Have you checked your code, looked for an infinite cycle?

Comment: Use a profiler and check where the application is working most of the time. I bet you'll come to some `while( !somecondition ){ Thread.sleep(100); }` ... or something alike.

Comment: @bcaceiro how do you do that?

Comment: @Fildor I'm really sorry but I am pretty much a noob and don't know what it is and how to do that. Can you please help me?

Comment: Submit your code, that will be helpful

Comment: Sumit, I'd be glad to help. But teaching you how to profile your application goes way beyond the scope of this site. Just google netbeans and profiler and you should get some tutorials.

Comment: Like this one : https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/profiler-intro.html

Comment: I edited the question and typed the code instead. Its the complete code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some serious issues with your code, but the immediate culprit for high CPU usage is this:

```
while(!AccountoBot.loggedIn)
    {
        jl.setText("LOG IN TO VIEW THIS SECTION");
        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        add(jl);
    }
```

You are on an infinite loop (at least until someone logs in) setting an UI element. It won't block the UI (because you started it in another thread), but will cause a very high CPU consumption.

You should check the official tutorial on [Swing and threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and maybe, after you've improved a bit, post on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a more detailed feedback for your code.

Comment: Thanks man! This really helped. I commented out the part you mentioned and then ran the project three times but the cpu usage didn't go above 4% !! The same thing earlier would bring the cpu to its knees. If its possible can you suggest me how to counter the login problem? Its basically a page to check if a valid user has logged on or not.

Comment: @SumitChakraborty Ideally you would create your UI with the "logged out" state and implement some sort of listener to update it when (for instance) the users click on the login button, without the need to keep checking whether the user is logged in or not. TBH, you probably don't need custom threads at all.

Comment: Thanks again for the swift reply :) I'm a noob trying to figure all this out so thanks for helping me out so quickly.